# Magento 2 Checkout Billing Address Modification

Tags: magento-2.1, knockoutjs

I have a custom module for checkout part, I just need to know how to modify some elements and for begin I am trying to place the Billing Address part on another side after shipping details.

I have that: 
checkout_index_index.xml

```
................
<item name="custom-billing" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Custom_Module/js/view/billing-address</item>
    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">custom-billing</item>
</item>
<item name="before-shipping-method-form" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">uiComponent</item>
     <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">before-shipping-method-form</item>
     <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
         <!-- address-list-additional-addresses -->
     </item>
</item>
...............
```

And inside web/templates/shipping.html

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- ko foreach: getRegion('custom-billing') -->
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

The component something want to display but it gives a js error:

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {id:'billing-address-same-as-shipping-'+ $parent.getCode()} }"
Message: $parent.getCode is not a function
at attr (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624),     <anonymous>:3:214)
at update (knockout.js:3659)
at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:3004)
at evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:1737)
at Object.ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:1946)
at knockout.js:3002
at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
at applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2836)
```

So Message: $parent.getCode is not a function, but I am stuck with this.

Anyone tried that?

Comment: Does this issue still persists?